# How to remove "._" files in a directory? Ubuntu

Tags: linux, command-line-interface, filesystems

Is there a command line to remove all "._foo.html" files in a directory on Unbuntu?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
rm ./._*
```

more stuff since it must be at least 15 characters.

Comment: Also, this resource http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1629 may be helpful in preventing their creation in the first place.

Comment: `./` is redundant.

Answer (score 37):

I use the following command to remove all of those annoying Apple files, but this one also does it recursively through all sub-directories, too:

```
# find . -iname '._*' -delete
```

Comment: +1 I came back to my question after I realized a recursive version of this command is what I really need. Thank you for adding the answer.

Comment: awesome. This one should be accepted as answer rather than the one above.

Comment: Or, more simply: `find . -iname "._*" -delete`

Comment: @ChristopherAltman, is this is really what you needed, you should accept this answer instead?

Comment: -name should be sufficient instead of -iname

Comment: If you get paranoid (like me) you can always do a "dry run" on these types of executable-finds by first running them sans-exec: `find . -iname '._*'`

Answer (score 1):

I use James' answer so often during webdevelopment I created my own command in 
`~/.bash_profile`

```
alias rmd=rmdotfiles
 rmdotfiles(){
   if [ -z "$1" ]; then
      local path=.
   else
      local path=$1
   fi

  find $path -iname '._*' -exec rm -rf {} \;
}
```

Remember to type `. ~/bash_profile` after editing the file to make it available.

EDIT:
Example usage: `rmd /path/to/dir`

Comment: Also I found that for Mac OSX Users working locally you can use a dot_clean command https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/136801/193609 and https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/dot_clean.1.html